# Is it possible to have an Express server for development and then a different server for production?

Tags: java, reactjs, webpack

If I have a React frontend (create-react-app) that I'm developing, I can also add an ExpressJS server and build and use it as a REST API. That works fine.

But say I have a Java backend that needs to be used in production and say that I make my Express endpoints the same as my Java endpoints. Is it possible to somehow use my ExpressJS backend during only development, and then have my app connect to my Java backend during production when it's deployed?

I've tried googling for this, but I haven't been able to find any articles that answer this question.

Comment: The frontend shouldn't care at all how the backend is implemented, as long as the API is the same. But it seems like a lot of unnecessary work to maintain a separate backend just for development.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly,

You want to know if it would be possible to use two different API's to supply data to your react app depending on if they are in development or production

in this case node/express in Dev and Java in production

the easiest way I can think of doing the above is by passing the relevant connection information to the react application via some kind of configuration/environment variable as long as the endpoints are exactly the same.

```
// When reaching out to api
fetch(process.env.newsApi)

//In Dev
process.env.newsApi = HTTPS://expressAPI

//In Prod
process.env.newsApi = HTTPS://JavaAPI
```